# Running test cases from web interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am doing a dash board(web page) where I am trying to integrate the smoke tests(coded UI tests) for different applications.

My problem :
I have multiple test projects/suites which are built to test different applications. I need to trigger the tests from a web based application by choosing which suite/set of test cases to run - like a one click triggering. I need to know if I can use a test controller or any other method to trigger the test suites/ set of test cases from the web application to execute the tests in a remote machine and give me the results.

I also heard that test agents and controllers can also trigger the test cases. But I have an overhead of calling or triggering the Test Controller from a Web interface like a click of button on the web page should be able to trigger the controller and run the test cases. Is there a method to trigger them ?

OR

I have even explored the MSTest.exe and VSTest.Console.exe methods of triggering the test cases from the web page, it works fine in the local machine, but when I host the website on IIS, it say **"To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the Desktop""**

The exception talks about test agents, but i have not used them at all. The exception doesn't make sense.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to do but what seems to be happening is the process that drives the tests is not started in interactive mode so it can not interact with the UI.  In the error message they probably assume you are using a standard setup, maybe starting a test run from Microsoft Test Manager or after a build by a build agent, the test agent or build agent that starts the test run must be in interactive mode so that they can interact with the desktop, for example imitate mouse clicks.

Comment: I don't want to use MTM to initiate the test cases, instead I am making a aspx page to initiate the test cases. I want some pointers on how to initiate test cases from aspx page and execute them remotely and get the result. So i even tried using test agents to execute the test cases. But i don't know how to trigger the test agent or a controller for that matter to start executing the test cases.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but with what ever process you do it, it must be run interactively.  My best guess is using the build agent in TFS, start it in interactive mode, and then use a powershell script to call tfs and order a build from some build configuration.  Then you could harvest data from the TestResults folder in the build path to display on your page.